# Data not passing to child component from parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-components

I have few checkboxes and I'm pushing those checkboxes values in to an array. Then I'm trying to access those data from child component using @Input decorator. But data is not even passing to the child component(Not displaying console.log). Could you please help me to fix this issue?

**Parent Component (.ts)**

```
public layers: any[] = [];

layerChange(e:any){
    var isChecked = e.target.checked;
    var id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
    const index = this.layers.findIndex(el => el.id === id);

    const layer = {
      isChecked: isChecked,
      id: id,
    }
    
    if(index > -1){
      this.layers[index].isChecked = isChecked;
    }else{
      this.layers.push(layer);
    }
    console.log(this.layers);
  }
```

**.html**

```
<input id="population" (change)="layerChange($event)" type="checkbox">
<input id="age" (change)="layerChange($event)" type="checkbox">
            

<app-esri-map [layerChange] = "layers"></app-esri-map>
```

**Child Component (.ts)**

```
 @Input() layerChange: Array<any>;
  console.log(layerChange)
```

Comment: Can you paste more of your child component? I'm not sure where your console is.

Comment: Angular change detection uses object reference by default, so pushing to the array or changing a value within the array will not fire any change. You need to set `layers` to a new instance.

Comment: Yeah, where is your console log, that is one of the most relevant parts of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead

```
public layers: any[] = [];

layerChange(e:any){
    var isChecked = e.target.checked;
    var id = e.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
    const index = this.layers.findIndex(el => el.id === id);

    const layer = {
      isChecked: isChecked,
      id: id,
    }
    
    if(index > -1){
      this.layers[index].isChecked = isChecked;
    }else{
      this.layers.push(layer);
    }
    this.layers = [...this.layers];
    console.log(this.layers);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah. This worked for me. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays are passed to children by reference.**

You're only pushing new items to your *layers* array, so the reference keeps the same. Thus, Angular's change detection cycle won't be triggered and the *OnChanges* lifecycle hook won't detect any changes on that *@Input*.

You need to create a new instance each time you change your array. Or just use a shared service between those components. That way the parent will push items to the array and the child will listen to those changes (using Observables).